# How to debug ACPI/poweroff problems?

Tags: acpi, dmesg

I recently replaced my hard drive with a Sandisk SSD and did a fresh install of Fedora 21 (previously using F20). Now my laptop won't power off, and I'm not sure which of the two is causing the problem. If I put it to sleep, the screen will blank but power remains on. If I shutdown, it hangs on the Fedora logo. Reboot works however. (Probably) relevant output from dmesg:

```
[    3.907523] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000428-0x000000000000042F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000400-0x000000000000047F (\PMIO) (20150204/utaddress-254)
[    3.907532] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[    3.907536] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000540-0x000000000000054F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x0000000000000563 (\GPIO) (20150204/utaddress-254)
[    3.907540] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[    3.910474] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000530-0x000000000000053F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x0000000000000563 (\GPIO) (20150204/utaddress-254)
[    3.910485] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[    3.912035] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000052F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x0000000000000563 (\GPIO) (20150204/utaddress-254)
[    3.912042] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[    3.912045] lpc_ich: Resource conflict(s) found affecting gpio_ich
[    3.912188] shpchp: Standard Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.4
[    3.912392] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x000000000000EFA0-0x000000000000EFBF conflicts with OpRegion 0x000000000000EFA0-0x000000000000EFAF (\_SB_.PCI0.SBUS.SMBI) (20150204/utaddress-254)
[    3.912399] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
```

How can I debug these kind of messages?

Comment: My guess would be that these ACPI warnings are irrelevant to your problem - they just mean some driver is trying to claim I/O address space which is used by some ACPI device. You're most likely seeing them due to different kernel versions being used in F20 and F21. If you don't know which change caused your problem, isolate them (I'd put my money on the SSD): try booting another distro's installation disk with a recent kernel (e.g. Arch) and then just do a `shutdown -h now`. If your box shuts down properly, file a Fedora bug (or try F22?). If it doesn't, update your BIOS and SSD firmware.